# Push Notifications for multiple users in multiple events

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building an app in which users can register themselves in events.

I'd like to send push notifications to the users registered in a particular event when, for example, the organizer makes a modification to the event.

Stack :

- Server : NodeJS, Graphql (Apollo), Firebase for authentication.
- Client : React-Native, Graphql (Apollo), Firebase for authentication.

For now I send in-app alerts using subscriptions, but I'd like to use push notifications so the users have the notification event if the app isn't launched.

I have read the docs of Firebase Cloud Messaging, and it uses topics to send notifications to users.
I could create a topic for each particular event, and have each user subscribe to each "event-topic" that corresponds to each event they are in, but this sounds like a misuse of FCM topics. To my understanding topics are made for a more general behavior, in the docs they only use topics like "weather", "highscores" ...

I'm not sure which approach I should use. Is the "one topic per event" wrong ? What are your thoughts about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topics actually sound like a great mapping for your use-case, as you could subscribe the users to the FCM topic (similar to how you already subscribe to to database ) to receive updates about the event.

The only thing to be aware of is that topics are public: any user can subscribe to any topic they know off. So in your case if you use the event ID as the topic, then anyone can subscribe to any event they know (or can guess) the ID of.

If that is a concern, you should not use topics and instead [manage your own tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens) and fan out from event ID to the FCM tokens of the folks who receive updates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I just figured out I will have to send individual notifications to some users in certain situations so I will opt for managing my own tokens.